# insert drop down list value in database in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want insert drop down list value in database from controller:

```
 public ActionResult PostMessage(ViewModel vm)
    {
        Models.Message messagetoPost = new Models.Message();
        ViewBag.Userlist = new SelectList(dbContext.Users, "Id", "UserName");
        ViewBag.Userlist = messagetoPost.MessageTosend;

        dbContext.Messages.Add(messagetoPost);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

View

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Userlist", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: ViewBag.Userlist = new SelectList(dbContext.Users, "Id", "UserName");
   ViewBag.Userlist = messagetoPost.MessageTosend;                                              
      Two times set the value then second time assigned value only bind in particular property.

Comment: I still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong signature. You need the selected value in your ViewModel, for example `UserId`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserId", ViewBag.Userlist, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

or better yet

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserId, ViewBag.Userlist, "Select User", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Finally, you have some other errors (assuming this is the POST method where you want to save). Copy the posted viewmodel fields into your Message entity and save (if no errors):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult PostMessage(ViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Models.Message messagetoPost = new Models.Message
        {
              UserId = vm.UserId;
              ... other fields
        };
        dbContext.Messages.Add(messagetoPost);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    // Failed, reset dropdown and return view with errors...
    ViewBag.Userlist = new SelectList(dbContext.Users, "Id", "UserName");
    return View(complianceItemViewModel);
}
```

Comment: As I mention, you have other issues. For instance, you are assigning values twice in a row to ViewBag.UserList so 2nd assignment wipes out the first. The above syntax is correct for a dropdown, so your issue most likely lies elsewhere. Show both the GET and POST methods for starters and tell us if you are even hitting the POST method, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownList("Userlist", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

change

```
 @Html.DropDownList("User",ViewBag.Userlist, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In this Place, **"User"** is the name of the Dropdown name

**ViewBag.UserList** is the options for the dropdown list

**null** is placed .if you need set the selected value of the dropdown

> Dropdown Control Name and ViewBag name is same than data not bind properly